# How to free up cursor after this in following code?

Tags: android

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {
            HistoryEntry._ID,
            HistoryEntry.COLUMN_HISTORY_INPUT,
            HistoryEntry.COLUMN_HISTORY_RESULT
    };
Cursor cursor = db.query(HistoryEntry.TABLE_NAME,
        projection,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null);
ListView historyListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mCursorAdaptor = new HistoryCursorAdaptor(this, cursor);
    historyListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdaptor);
```

//the code is using to read data from database but error in query. says ," free up cursor after use."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to call `cursor.close()` to release the cursor and its resources but as per your code, once we close the `cursor` then your adapter won't be able to access it, so the idle place will be to close the cursor inside `onDestroy` method of activity life cycle and for that, you can declare cursor as global variable (outside current method)

Comment: thank you it worked. but if i have to move the cursor to first position after  deleting the table data in above code. what can i do?

Comment: i guess you mean , you want to display the first list item in the listview , you can use `historyListView.setSelection(0);` or your desired index value and i am glad that we could help, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `HistoryCursorAdaptor` is a `CursorAdapter`, it takes ownership of the passed in `Cursor` and you should not be closing it yourself.

If you want to explicitly close the cursor owned by a cursor adapter, you can call `changeCursor(null)` on the adapter.